# Add signed integer to unsigned in C#

Tags: c#, types, unsigned, signed

Even though it sounds simple, C# makes it a hard job to add a signed integer (an offset) to an unsigned value:

```
unsigned uintValue;
int offset;
// ...
uintValue += offset; // causes error CS0266
```

This can be done by converting the offset to a signed value, but this looks somewhat unsafe and hakish to me, and it is risky if the offset is of a smaller type than `uintValue`.
Is there an elegant solution for this simple problem, without using tons of ugly type conversions?

In my application, `offset` can either be a positive or a negative number, otherwise the solution would be trivial.

Comment: "This can be done by converting the offset to a signed value" It already is.

Comment: No,  and type conversions aren't hacky at, just do with uintValue based on the value of offset.

Answer (score 1):

A cast is necessary here. Concider the following:

```
uIntValue = ( offset < 0 ?
               uIntValue - (uint)(offset * (-1)) :
               uIntValue + (uint)(offset) );
```

It means that if offset is negative, it will make it positive and reduce it from uIntValue,
and if offset is positive, it will simply add it

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways of doing it safely; unfortunately, neither one is particularly elegant:

- Convert both operands to `long` to guarantee enough bits, perform an operation, and cast the result back to `unsigned`, or
- Make a conditional based on the sign of `offset`, and use `+` or `-` with the absolute value of the offset, appropriately cast to `unsigned`.

The first approach is easier to code, but slightly more wasteful, because it takes an extra four bytes:

```
uintValue = (unsigned)((long)uintValue + offset);
```

However, it is free of conditionals, so it may be faster in the end.

**Note:** It goes without saying that this scheme produces an invalid result when the result of addition is negative.

Comment: In a checked arithmetic context the above will fail if the unsigned value wraps around.  Depending upon what it's used for that could be good or bad.  It's too bad the bitwise `&` operator doesn't have overloads for `UInt32 & UInt64 -> Uint32`, `UInt32 & Int64 -> Uint32`, `UInt64 & UInt32 -> UInt32`, and `Int64 & UInt32 -> Uint32`, since such overloads would avoid a silly cast when bit-masking the computational result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the operand to the same type, compensating for possible negative values:

```
        uint uintValue = 1000;
        int offset = -1000;
        uintValue = (offset < 0 ? uintValue - (uint)(-1 * offset) : uintValue + (uint)offset);
```